# SSRS REPORT BUILDER 3.0 HOW TO GET SELECTED INPUT PARAMETERS DESCRIPTION

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008-r2

I am new to SSRS REPORT BUILDER 3.0 . I am passing 2 input  parameters to  to get the report .1: Employee No 2:Date  and retrieving employee details on the report.  Now i want to show  the employee name for selected employee no on the report . But how to get this  information (EX: i know the query from employee table where emp no =@empno). But how and where i can write this query for input parameter @empno. So that i can drag and drop employee name on my report ? LIKE CRYSTAL REPORTS...
Any help or comments would be great ..

I DONT KNOW IT IS A RIGHT APPROACH:

1 CREATING DATASET and query :
SELECT EMPNAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPNO='@EMPNO'
2: CREATE PARAMETER 
GENERAL: INTERNAL 
AVAILABLE VALUES: DATASET , VALUE FIELD, LABEL FIELD

BUT ITS NOT WORKING

Comment: To my knowledge, SSRS doesn't support drag-and-drop functionality for setting parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

I would create 3 data sets 
1 for select * from emp tables  where empno = @empno AND  date =@date
2 one for select empno from table for the empno paramater.
3 select date from table where empno = @empno.

then build your report and parameters and the two parameters will correspond with each other.